# Origin of "moke," used in the mildly derogatory term "you lil' moke"

Tags: meaning, etymology, animals

Does anyone know the origins of this term? I have only managed to track one reference to it. I heard it from my Granny who was Romani. The [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=moke) has this short entry:

> **moke (n.)** "dolt," 1855, originally (16c.) "donkey;" of unknown origin, perhaps originally a personal name. In U.S., "black person," from 1856.

Comment: I haven't heard of *moke*. I've heard of *mook*. And my father used to called me and my brother a pair of *noodniks*, a term which has sadly fallen into disuse (along with "you dirty *bum*).

Comment: ha! noodniks? thats a great one!

Comment: You  would probably get better answers if you showed you did some research first. For starters, you could link a definition, such as [this one](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/moke), and what you found about its origins, such as [this link](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=moke). Users will probably put more effort in crafting a nice, complete, referenced answer if they see you put some effort too.

Comment: slang for hot chocolate that tastes like coffee, *ydr!* aka. mocha?

Comment: Looking at the links in the comment from @Yay you can see that the term basically means "donkey".  The derogatory meaning should be easy to derive from that.  (You should have done this research already, and included it in your question, if you still had one.)

Comment: The question is now fine, with references and everything, and it has a terrific answer. We don't need to be retroactively punitive if it is not serving any end. I have voted to re-open.

Comment: @DanBron - "Noodnik" has not fallen into disuse - perhaps you have distanced yourself from the population where it is commonly used? (Hint: it's Yiddish.)

Comment: @Oldbag I live about a mile from where I grew up, in the same neighborhood. And yes, it's Yiddish, and about half my friends are stereotypical NY jews, and most of their parents are like George's from *Seinfeld*. Within a few blocks are several synagogues and a Hebrew school. I also have a large contingent of Israeli buddies, but they skew much more to Hebrew than Yiddish. Anyway, I haven't heard anyone actually use *noodnik* since I was a kid. It's just one of those words a previous generation used, like, as I said, *bum* (as a dysphemistic term of endearment).

Comment: @DanBron - Hmm... Well there's your answer. You haven't moved - everyone else did. I'm sure there's a neighborhood in Florida where the "noodnik"s fly like palmetto bugs, on a summer night.

Comment: This may be of interest: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_Moke from the British meaning of "donkey"

Answer (score 6):

***'Moke' in U.S. slang***

As a U.S. slang term, *moke* has a very problematic history. Though its earliest slang meaning (going back at least to 1839), was "donkey or mule," it was also used for decades as a disparaging term for "a black or dark-skinned person" (starting not later than 1847) and "a foolish or inconsequential fellow" (starting not later than 1855).

J.E. Lighter, *Random House Historical Dictionary of American Slang* (1997) identifies three basic meanings of the term in connection with living creatures:

> **moke** *n.* {orig[in] unk[nown]} **1.a.** a donkey or mule. *Rare in U.S.* **b.** a horse. [Citations range from 1839 to 1960.] ...
>
> **2.a.**  a black person.—usu. used contemptuously.—usu. considered offensive. ... **b.** a dark-skinned person of any race.—usu. used contemptuously.—usu. considered offensive. [Citations range from 1847 to 1967.] ...
>
> **3.** a foolish or inconsequential fellow. Cf. MOOK. [Citations range from 1855 to 1915] ...

So historically in U.S. usage, a *moke* could refer to a beast of burden; a black or dark-skinned person; or a fool or lightweight.

George Matsell, [*Vocabulum; or The Rogue's Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=07NZAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA25&dq=%22Dib.+Portion+or+share%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GjPxVLLKJ9PVoASKh4GAAg&ved=0CB4Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=moke&f=false) (1859) is one of the earliest glossaries to list *moke*:

> MOKE: A negro.

James Maitland, *The American Slang Dictionary* (1891) indicates that the first two meanings cited by Lighter were used in different parts of the world:

> **Moke,** in England a donkey; in the United States a negro.

---

***Theories of the term's origin***

As for the source of the word (which Lighter says is unknown), different theories have appeared over the years. Maximilian Schele de Vere, [*Americanisms: The English of the New World*](https://books.google.com/books?id=C-wIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA4&dq=%22Americanisms:+The+English+of+the+New+World%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zixIU5GyCIakyQH9-4HoBw#v=onepage&q=%22moke%22&f=false) (1872) has this for *moke*:

> *Moke*, possibly a remnant of the obsolete *moky*, which is related to "murky," is used in New York to designate an old fogy or any old person, disrespectfully spoken to. A hackdriver is thus represented to reply to a stranger who had upbraided him for his violent language, "See here, my lively *moke*, said he, you sling on too much style." (Galveston [Texas] *News*, May 4, 1871.) In the Northwest the term is generally applied to negroes, with whom the original "murky" may be associated in some minds. "The young *mokes*, who had often denounced Mr. Ham for having incurred the displeasure of his aged sire, in consequence of which their heads were covered with tufts of hair." (Dubuque [Iowa] *Herald*, 1871.)

"Billy Bilger" [Andrew Pendleton], [*The Silly Syclopedia: Containing "daffynishuns" of the Words of the Slang Language Spoken by the Midshipmen of the U.S. Naval Academy*](https://books.google.com/books?id=A1IWAAAAYAAJ&pg=PT48&dq=%22mess+hall+moke%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiih4Ssx9jLAhUC9GMKHShLDuwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22mess%20hall%20moke%22&f=false) (1908) has this:

> MOKES—(From the Spanish *Mozo* meaning servant.) The sons Ham with waiter's billets. Blackheads on the face of the earth.

An illustration of "mess hall moke" in the same book clarifies that Naval Academy midshipmen used the term to refer to (African American) food servers and table bussers in the mess hall.

Harold Wentworth & Stuart Flexner, *Dictionary of American English*, first edition (1960) has this:

> **moke** *n.* **1** {derog.} A Negro, esp. a Negro minstrel. **1856:** *D[ictionary of] A[merican] E[nglish]*. **1899:** "Smoky Mokes," title of a pop. song. *Obs. From "mocha."* **2** {derog.} A Filipino. *Some c1930 USN[avy] use.* **3** An easy-going fellow; one who habitually asks favors; a bore. *Some c1900 use.* **4** A horse, esp. an inferior race horse; a plug. *Not common in U.S. but fairly common in Australia.* *adj.* Dark; black; Negroid. *Not common.*

To sum up, the suggested source words are *murky* (suggested in 1872), *mozo* (suggested in 1908), and *mocha* (suggested in 1960).

---

***The Romani connection***

John Hotten, [*The Slang Dictionary: Or, The Vulgar Words, Street Phrases, and "Fast" Expressions of High and Low Society*](https://books.google.com/books?id=diRKAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA180&dq=%22Moke+a+donkey+gipsy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja5K7A69jLAhUG32MKHQGCBskQ6AEILTAD#v=onepage&q=%22Moke%20a%20donkey%20gipsy%22&f=false) (1864) alludes to an alternative etymological explanation that may be of special interest to the poster:

> MOKE, a donkey.—*Gipsy*.

The 1874 edition of Hotten, [*The Slang Dictionary: Etymological, Historical, and Anecdotal*](https://books.google.com/books?id=l3MKAAAAIAAJ&pg=PA227&dq=%22Moke+a+donkey+gipsy%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja5K7A69jLAhUG32MKHQGCBskQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Moke%20a%20donkey%20gipsy%22&f=false), expands this entry considerably:

> **Moke,** a donkey.—*Gipsy*, but now general to all the lower orders. A "coster" and his "moke" are almost inseparable terms. Probably derived originally from the Arabic *al mocreve*, a carrier.

Hotten's dictionary was published in London, and he is clearly concerned with the British English meaning of the slang term *moke*. A [letter by William Cumming Wilde](https://books.google.com/books?id=wQ48AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA95&dq=%22Moke+a+negro%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi4_9iU5djLAhVEKGMKHVuqB1QQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Moke%20a%20negro%22&f=false), published in *American Notes and Queries* (December 22, 1888) follows up on the etymological question:

> MOKE, a negro (Matsell's "Vocabulum, or Rogues' Lexicon," New York, 1859). *Moke*, a donkey, Gipsy, but now general to all the lower orders ("The Slang Dictionary," London, 1873). *Meila moila, and not moke*, is the English Gipsy for donkey. In Stratman ("Dictionay of Old English," 1873) we find: *Moke*; Swed. mocka, *moke*, etc. *Moke* (môk-mok?), moke, tined; but neither of these would seem to be the *moke* that appears above. The English Gipsy and *Moker*, to foul, dirty—Smart and Crofton, "Dialect of the English Gipsies," 1875—may seem to be the source from whence we get *moke*, but we object to this; *moker* is not to be seen in any other Gipsy, except the English; nothing in any way like it can be found in the Gipsy dialects of Norway, Germany or Spain.
>
> In "Paspati Études sur les Tchinghaianés ou Bohemiens de l'empire Ottoman," it is true, we have *mokára* peindre, tacher, graisser, but this would hardly seem to suggest *moke*. In our Old English, we find *mokey* defined cloudy, and so may be allowed to suppose that *moker* is quite as likely to be English as Gipsy. Certain it is *moke* existed in our English literature at least one hundred and fifty years before the first Gipsy appeared int he British Isles. "Crist," says Wycliffe, "gave his life for hise breper, & so rewled his shepe; pei wolen not gyne her moke to help here nedy brepern, but leten here shep perishen." ...
>
> *Moke*, in Wycliffe's Treatise, evidently expresses *servant*, *menial*, even if it may be suggestive of something that is filthy or foul. The reverend doctor [James Todd, D.D. Dublin]'s troubles [in identifying the meaning of *moke* in Wycliffe] may, at least, teach us a lesson; *thief talk* is not without its uses, and it is certainly not *gibberish*, as some suppose.

These references suggest sources of *moke* in Arabic *al mocreve* (in 1874), in "English Gipsy" *mokar* (in 1875), in Swedish *mocka* (in 1877), and in Old English *mokey* (in 1888).

---

***Conclusions***

Whatever the original source of *moke* in the British English sense of "donkey" may have been, the fact that it was identified with "English Gipsy" slang by 1864 and that it appears to have been used as a term of endearment (or perhaps of affectionate exasperation) by a Romani grandmother more than a hundred years later is fascinating to me. To judge from the OP's anecdotal evidence, the Romani English sense of *moke* does not appear to have been tainted by the derogatory U.S. English sense of *moke* as "dark-skinned person."

Answer (score 1):

"See here, my lively moke, said he, you sling on too much style." (Galveston [Texas] News, May 4, 1871.

This quote is a reference to a blackface song-and-dance routine popularized on the American variety stage by Johnny Thompson and later by William J. Ashcroft and other minstrel performers. The lively (or "musical") moke danced, sang and played various instruments. Ashcroft later did much the same routine in Irish character with "MacNamara's Band."